# Regular expressions matching across multiple line in Sublime Text

Tags: python, regex

My data follow a repeated pattern in a text file. The same type data structure with unique values is printed out till the end of the file

```
{'AuthorSite': None,
 'FirstText': None,
 'Image': None,
 'SrcDate': None,
 'Title': None,
 'Url': None}
...
..
.
```

I am trying to match each block one at a time using a regular expression in sublime text. I have tried a variety of forms with no success. The latest one being:

```
\{(.|\s)\}
```

I wanted to hoover up everything between each pair of braces. Please advise. I will eventually implement this in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\{([^}]+)\}
```

You can try this demo:

http://regex101.com/r/hQ9xT1/32

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'{([^}]+)}')
test_str = u"{'AuthorSite': None,\n 'FirstText': None,\n 'Image': None,\n 'SrcDate': None,\n 'Title': None,\n 'Url': None}"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

Your regex `\{(.|\s)\}` didn't work because you had not quantified it. Use `\{(?:.|\s)+\}`.

Comment: Very good, in Sublime it must be entered as \{([^}]+)\} to work. Can you explain the regex in plain English please.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to retrieve the values, I would use the following regular expression

```
\{([^\}]+)\}
```

The key here is [^}] character class, which matches *anything* that isn't the literal } character. Whitespaces, border characters, letters, digits, etc.

Here is the Python code:

```
import re
hoover_exp = re.compile(r'\{([^\}]+)\}')
with(open('data.txt', 'r') as infile):
    text = infile.read()
matches = hoover_exp.findall(text)
```

matches will be a list of all the non-overlapping matches in text. e.g.

> ["'AuthorSite': None,\n 'FirstText': None,\n 'Image': None,\n 'SrcDate': None,\n 'Title': None,\n 'Url': None",
>    "'AuthorSite': None,\n 'FirstText': None,\n 'Image': None,\n 'SrcDate': None,\n 'Title': None,\n 'Url': None"]

That being said, if you input text is nothing but these dicts, you might be better off using something like json to pull them directly into Python dicts.

Comment: Your regular expression falls short in two ways:
1st: You don't provide any quantifier (a repeat operator e.g. * + ?) So it only matches strings like {a} or { } or {\n}
2nd: Even with a quantifier, the '}' literal character is captured by the '.' operator, and since regular expressions are greedy by default, if you have two such braced groups next to each other, you'll grab both in the same group. Not what you want I expect. So if your regular expression were \{(.|\s)+?\} I think you would have more luck.